# How to make window topbars dark in ubuntu 13.10 and Cinnamon?

Tags: themes, cinnamon

I am currently running Ubuntu 13.10, cinnamon, and I have the theme minty. I am, unfortunately, a perfectionist and if everything isn't exactly how I like it, it really gets on my nerves.

As you can see in this picture, there is a white bar at the top of my applications. I really want to get rid of it and make it dark (I can make the application theme dark, but not the top bar using gnome tweak).

How can I change it?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cinnamon, you need to go to "Themes", then "Other Settings" and then "Window Borders". If you only have Adwaita, then you need to install some GTK themes, not shell themes and then you can change the top bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try these.
from desktop right click->Change desktop background.
click on the 'theme' item menu.
then you get a list of themes..
i guess the theme you are looking for is "Ambiance".

Comment: I already, have the theme "Minty" installed, and I want to keep it!